# populate dropdown with spring mapping url

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, spring

I am working on spring project with angular js .I have two dropdowns ,one for country list and second for citylist.

I am getting my json from spring controller for both country and city .

I am able to get country list in my country drop-down but i want to pass countrycode of selected country with city list URL because my spring controller mapping is like:-**country/{id}/city** for getting city list according to city id.

I want that if i send country code as query string instead of {id} in city URL ,so that i can get city list with based on country id every time based on selected country.

Here is my html code:

```
<form data-ng-submit="submit()" data-ng-controller="MyController"
         >
        <h3>{{headerText}}</h3>
        {{formData}}<br> <br>
        <div data-ng-init="getCountry()">

            <select id="countrylist"
                style="border-radius: 10px; width: 210px; height: 40px"
                data-ng-model="Countryselected"
                data-ng-options=" country.cntryName for country in getCountries"
                data-ng-click="getCity()">
                <option value="">Select Country</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <select style="border-radius: 10px; width: 210px; height: 40px"
                data-ng-model="cityselect" data-ng-disabled="!Countryselected"
                data-ng-options=" c.cityName for c in availableCities "
                data-ng-click="getPlace()">
                <option value="">Select City</option>
            </select>
```

Here is my javascript:-

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app
                    .controller(
                            'MyController',
                            function($scope, $http) {

                                $scope.getCountry = function() {

                                    $http(
                                            {
                                                method : 'GET',
                                                url : 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/newclue/country/list'
                                            }).success(
                                            function(data, status, headers,
                                                    config) {
                                                $scope.getCountries = data;
                                            }).error(
                                            function(data, status, headers,
                                                    config) {
                                                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                                // or server returns response with an error status.
                                            });
                                };


                                $scope.getCity = function() {
                                    $scope.availableCities = [];

                                    $http(
                                            {
                                                method : 'GET',
                                                url : 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/newclue/country/{id}/cities'
                                            }).success(
                                            function(data, status, headers,
                                                    config) {
                                                $scope.getCities = data;
                                            }).error(
                                            function(data, status, headers,
                                                    config) {
                                                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                                // or server returns response with an error status.
                                            });
```

Here is my country list json:-

```
 [{"cntryCode":1,"cntryName":"India"},{"cntryCode":2,"cntryName":"Australia"},{"cntryCode":3,"cntryName":"Pakistan"},{"cntryCode":4,"cntryName":"America"}]
```

Here is my city list json:-

```
[{"cityCode":1,"cityName":"banglore"},{"cityCode":2,"cityName":"manglore"},{"cityCode":3,"cityName":"aus1"},{"cityCode":4,"cityName":"sydney"},{"cityCode":5,"cityName":"lahore"},{"cityCode":6,"cityName":"Islamabad"},{"cityCode":7,"cityName":"Newyork"},{"cityCode":8,"cityName":"Newyork2"}]
```

Comment: if i send country id with url ,suppose if country id is 1 it will take id 1 as quuery string and it will go with city url to spring controller and then through mapping that is country/{id}/city ,it will take value 1 as id and it will send  citycode 1 with cityname. and that's my requirement .please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do is change `data-ng-click="getCity()"` to `data-ng-change="getCity()"` in your HTML, you want the event to trigger once the user has selected the country. Last thing you need to do is change the URL which you are calling in `getCity()` function, change it to:

```
url : 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestCrud/newclue/country/' + $scope.Countryselected.cntryCode  + '/cities'
```

Hope this helps